# Functional behaviour of Spark's DataFrameReader.csv method?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am spinning up on Python, Spark, and PySpark.  I am following [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/#read-directory)
on reading all CSV files in a specified directory, i.e.,
`spark.read.csv(DirectoryPath)`.  I tried to find where the
description of *which* files are read, e.g., *all* files regardless of
extension or just files with the CSV extension.  I consider it to be a
very basic expectation for the documentation to describe this
behaviour.  The `spark.read` method returns a `DataFrameReader`
object, of which `csv` is a method.

The doc string from entering `spark.read.csv?` at the Spyder IPython
console only seems to describe the case where a CSV file path is
provided, not where a directory path is given.  The [PySpark
documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html)
says essentially the same thing.

Since Spark is written in Scala, I sometimes found the Scala
documentation better.  However, none of the descriptions for the
[three `csv`
methods](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html)
seem to describe the case where the path argument is a directory
rather than a file.

**What *is* the functional description of `DataFrameReader.csv`?**

I am using Spark 3.4.1, which was determined by the Anaconda package
manager on Windows 10 as compatible with a Python 3.9 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark data sources share a lot of common behaviour and that's why the documentation is split into generic and source-specific parts. The functional description of the CSV data source is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-data-sources-csv.html). There is a link to this page in the Scala docs of one of the `.csv()` overloads. By default, if provided a directory, the source will try to load each and every file as a CSV file. You can change that behaviour by setting a [glob filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-glob-filter) with `.option("pathGlobFilter", "*.csv")`. Path globbing is a generic trait shared by the file-based data sources and as such is described in one of the generic sections of the SQL data sources guide.

Comment: Thank you, Hristo.  The link from the first `.csv() overloads` is described a for options.  I didn't initially follow that link because I was trying to restrict the amount of new material that I had to figure out, and I wasn't trying to specify options.  But you're right, the more complete description of `.csv()` is at the *top* of the page containing the options section that is linked to.

Comment: Thank you also for the `pathGlobFilter` option and the pointer to the generic sections of the SQL data sources guide.  It's invaluable to be aware of how distributed the description of functionality is.

Comment: @user2153235 just as with any other large project with an extensive API, Spark's documentation is laid out in a certain way and takes some getting to know before it start making sense.